# description method is not getting called

Tags: ios, objective-c

I created example to learn some basics in objective-c. I have a class called Person as shown below. in the main method I try to call `description` method to print some data, and AFAIK, `description method` is similar to `toString` in java..but `description` method I created is not called

please have a look at the code below and let me know why the contents of `description` method is not called.

**person.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Person : NSObject {
    int age;
    int weight;
}

-(void) setAge:(int) age;
-(void) setWeight: (int) weight;

-(int) getAge;
-(int) getWeight;

-(NSString *) description;

@end
```

**person.m**

```
#import "Person.h"

@implementation Person

-(void) setAge:(int) a {
    age = a;
}

-(void) setWeight:(int) w {
    weight  = w;
}

-(int) getAge {
    return age;
}

-(int) getWeight {
    return weight;
}

-(NSString *) description {
    NSString *desc = @("my age is: %i and my weight is: %i", age, weight);
    NSLog(@"%@", desc);
    return desc;
}
@end
```

**main**:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Person.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {

        Person *me = [[Person alloc] init];

        [me setAge:20];
        [me setWeight:55];

        NSString *desc = [me description];
        NSLog(@"%@", desc);

        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked putting ___break point___ in your code? Or you aren't getting log message, and assuming that the method isn't being called at all?

Comment: @nayem thats why I added NSLog inside description method..the slog message is not printed

Comment: `NSString *desc = @("my age is: %i and my weight is: %i", age, weight);` That's a weird way to create a `NSString` `stringWithFormat:`.

Comment: Did not you get a compilation error on the line starting with `NSString *desc =...`? This should not compile at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have the call to `description` method, but you aren't getting the log message. Problem is in the `NSString` that you produced. This is not valid:

```
NSString *desc = @("my age is: %i and my weight is: %i", age, weight);
```

Try changing this to:

```
NSString *desc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"my age is: %i and my weight is: %i", age, weight];
```

Comment: do you think I should add signature to the description method in person.h??

Comment: `- (NSString *)description` and `+ (NSString *)description` are methods of `NSObject`. So they are inherited in all of your subclasses. So you don't essentially need to add the signatures to your header files.